# DataTables how to disable Request if table reaches breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to know if there is a way to disable the requests if the table reaches a breakpoint. What do I mean with that? Every time the table hides something, the table makes a new request to the server. When someone plays with it, a lot of requests are going to the server. Sure, I can handle it on the server side, but is there an easier option, that datatables uses the same data which is displaying at the moment?

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '../api/data',
            stateSave: true,
            responsive: true,
            "deferRender": true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind I found the solution. It's pretty easy but I overlooked it. The solution is to use a pipeline, which caches the data. [DataTables Pipeline Example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)